# Cannot Run Command On Android

Tags: java, android, sh

Im making a script to run a ARMv7 port of java and I always get this

exec sh -c '/data/java/bin/java '
u0_a192@android:/ $ exec sh -c '/data/java/bin/java '
sh: /data/java/bin/java: not found
I have verifyed the file is there and all the required files are there
With root:

`exec sh -c '/data/java/bin/java '
u0_a192@android:/ # exec sh -c '/data/java/bin/java '
sh: /data/java/bin/java: not found`

And Before I ran 
`chmod -R 755 *` 
In my main folder containing the .jar I want to run and the java files

What im a doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that a) `/data/java/bin/java` actually is a Java Runtime Environment and b) `/data/java/bin/java` is (an) executable?

Comment: Post the results of running this command: ls -l /data/java/bin/java*

Comment: You did a (likely unnecessary) chmod on the .jar files, but did you do one on the JRE?  Why do you have an extra space at the end of the filename?

Comment: @HannoBinder Yes, Im Sure

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes chmod 0755 on every file,
extra space?

Comment: @scottt -rwxr-xr-x root   root    5916 2014-40-10 21:44 java

Comment: '/data/java/bin/java ' has an extra space between java and ' - although in my testing that did not seem to matter, it's still in the category of things to watch out for.